# Field from abstract class inside where clause

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Hello i have following entites:

```
abstract Entity A {

long id;

boolean sharedField;

}
```

```
Entity B extends A {

string specificField;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_c")
private C c;
    
}
```

```
Entity C {

long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "c", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Where(clause = "sharedField = 'something'")
private List<B> bList;

}
```

So from Hibernate i get **Unknown column 'b.shared_field' in 'where clause'**

Note that i have table A in my DB with id and shared_field columns, and in table B i have id (same as one in table A), id_c and specific_field.

Is there some way that i could indicate to Hibernate (trough Where clause or some other way) that i only want to have only those rows from B table that meet following criteria.

### I tried adding NamedQuery but that didnt work.

**UPDATE**

Ive manged to find the way. This is @Where clause i used:

```
@Where(clause = "id IN (SELECT a.id FROM A a WHERE a.id = id AND a.shared_field = 'something')")
```

Comment: Two problems I see here: 1) I don't see the `@Entity` annotation being used anywhere, and 2) the `sharedField` field is boolean, so it makes no sense to compare it against a string literal.

Comment: Its pseudo code, everything is written well and i didnt actually copy code from my project i just described problem.

Comment: You will get help here for whatever code you post.  If your real code be something different, then you should have posted that.

Comment: Maybe instead of focusing on trivial things you should give some suggestion on real issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Where(clause = "id IN (SELECT a.id FROM A a WHERE a.id = id AND a.shared_field = 'something')")